# Count unique values with multiple criteria in excel

Tags: excel, count, unique

| ITEM | Duration | Type | Participants | Schedule1 | Schedule2 | Schedule3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACTIVITY1 | 1 | Type 1 | 1 | 4/1/2021 |  | 4/1/2021 |
| ACTIVITY2 | 1 | Type 3 | 1220 | 4/1/2021 | 4/1/2021 | 4/1/2021 |
| ACTIVITY3 | 2 | Type 2 | 2 | 4/1/2021 | 4/1/2021 | 4/1/2021 |
| ACTIVITY1 | 3 | Type 1 | 1378 | 4/2/2021 | 4/2/2021 | 4/2/2021 |
| ACTIVITY2 | 14 | Type 1 | 1 | 4/3/2021 | 4/3/2021 | 4/3/2021 |
| ACTIVITY3 | 8 | Type 1 | 1421 | 4/3/2021 | 4/3/2021 | 4/3/2021 |
| ACTIVITY3 | 7 | Type 1 | 1250 | 4/3/2021 | 4/3/2021 | 4/3/2021 |
| ACTIVITY1 | 1 | Type 2 | 1 | 4/7/2021 | 4/7/2021 | 4/7/2021 |
| ACTIVITY2 | 1 | Type 1 | 1 | 4/8/2021 | 4/8/2021 | 4/8/2021 |
| ACTIVITY3 | 1 | Type 1 | 1404 | 4/9/2021 | 4/9/2021 | 4/9/2021 |
| ACTIVITY4 | 6 | Type 2 | 2 | 4/10/2021 | 4/10/2021 | 4/10/2021 |
| ACTIVITY1 | 1 | Type 1 | 1387 | 4/11/2021 | 4/11/2021 | 4/11/2021 |
| ACTIVITY8 | 18 | Type 1 | 1 | 4/11/2021 | 4/11/2021 | 4/11/2021 |
| ACTIVITY9 | 1 | Type 1 | 1421 | 4/11/2021 | 4/11/2021 | 4/11/2021 |
| ACTIVITY7 | 3 | Type 3 | 1 | 4/13/2021 | 4/13/2021 | 4/13/2021 |
| ACTIVITY2 | 5 | Type 1 | 1227 | 4/15/2021 | 4/15/2021 | 4/15/2021 |
| ACTIVITY6 | 6 | Type 3 | 1 | 4/15/2021 | 4/15/2021 | 4/15/2021 |
| ACTIVITY1 | 4 | Type 1 | 211 | 4/18/2021 | 4/18/2021 | 4/18/2021 |
| ACTIVITY2 | 9 | Type 1 | 1 | 4/19/2021 | 4/19/2021 | 4/19/2021 |
| ACTIVITY1 | 9 | Type 1 | 1 | 4/21/2021 | 4/21/2021 | 4/21/2021 |
| ACTIVITY3 | 5 | Type 4 | 1 | 4/22/2021 | 4/22/2021 | 4/22/2021 |
| ACTIVITY2 | 2 | Type 1 | 1 | 4/22/2021 | 4/22/2021 | 4/22/2021 |
| ACTIVITY5 | 1 | Type 1 | 1 | 4/25/2021 | 4/25/2021 | 4/25/2021 |
| ACTIVITY4 | 1 | Type 1 | 1 | 4/30/2021 | 4/30/2021 | 4/30/2021 |

I just want to count the number of activities per day per type on a separate sheet (Schedule) based on the table.

So for April 1, count should be three. April 2 is one, April 3 is one.

So far I have below formula for April 1 but it's just counting the items based on the date.

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[[Schedule1]:[Schedule3]],">"&DATE(2021,4,1)+TIME(0,0,0),Table1[[Schedule1]:[Schedule3]],"<="&DATE(2021,4,1)+TIME(23,59,59))
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a [pivot table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

Comment: Thanks @NicholasHunter. However, I'm creating a calendar table. Using a pivot table wont be a pretty solution. I want to see the days where count is zero so that I know which dates I can add more activities.

Comment: Maybe you should show what your desired output looks like. When you say "per day, per type", do you want the days as row headers and the types as column headers?--or what exactly? Are schedules1, 2, and 3 always going to be the same on each row? If not, how would that work? Do you want to count the same activity for each of the two or three different dates?

Comment: Why is `April 3 => 1`?  Seems you have, for that date, `Activity 2 - Type 1` and `Activity 3 - Type1`. Maybe if you explain your logic better, and show your desired output given your posted data, things will be more clear.  Or is that you just want the number of different Types per day, without regard to the number of Activities?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula where I2 = "Type" and J2 = a date.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Type]=I2)*(((Table1[Schedule1]=J2)+(Table1[Schedule2]=J2)+(Table1[Schedule3]=J2))>0))
```

The formula will count where type is as specified in I2 and the date in J2 appears in any of the 3 Schedule columns at least once.